# iOS Core Plot X Axis text + icon

Tags: ios, image, indexing, core-plot

Hope you people doing great.I am new to Core Plot api and need your suggestion.I want to customize x index of plot and wants to add icon and label to each index.As I have searched , I got to make policy none to index but I want to add image to each label.Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Custom axis labels don't have to be just text. The label's `contentLayer` can be any `CPTLayer`. Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you could render your text and label into an image and use that as the `fill` for a `CPTBorderedLayer`, add the icon (in a bordered layer) as a sublayer to the text layer for the label, or even create a custom `CPTLayer` subclass that draws everything the way you want it.